# How to show full results, rather than matched text from regex searches in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re, findall

I am creating a script that searches for a file based on a keyword, my output should be the whole observation, rather than just the matched text, but I'm finding .group doesn't work on this.

```
import re 
import os 
 
pers_info = pd.read_csv(r".....StateWorkforceMailingList_2-7-19a.csv",encoding='utf-8')

Pers_info['State'] = Texas, Florida etc... 

 files=os.listdir(r"....\State Files")
 
Files = list of WORKFORCE_2017_ALABAMA_FILE.xlsx,...,n

matches=re.findall(pers_info.State[4], files.replace("_", " "),re.I)
print(match)
```

My intended output is WORKFORCE_2017_ALABAMA_FILE.xlsx
Instead I get 'Alabama'

Should I try a boolean mask ?

Comment: Is this the full code? Also could you make a better example that includes you dictionary?

Comment: No - this is a snippet of a larger mailmerge code- I intend to match the state with their file so I can send each state their specific attachment.  
The Pers_info['State'] is a dataframe and the files is just a list of file a file folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> Pers_info = pd.DataFrame({'State':['Texas', 'Alabama', 'Florida']})
>>> Files = ['WORKFORCE_2017_ALABAMA_FILE.xlsx', 'WORKFORCE_2017_FILE.xlsx']
>>> pattern = re.compile(rf'(?<![^\W_])(?:{"|".join(Pers_info["State"].to_list())})(?![^\W_])', re.I)
>>> list(filter(pattern.search, Files))
['WORKFORCE_2017_ALABAMA_FILE.xlsx']
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/lGgmhD/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\W_]                   any character except: non-word
                             characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _),
                             '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Texas                    'Texas'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Alabama                  'Alabama'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Florida                  'Florida'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\W_]                   any character except: non-word
                             characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _),
                             '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Thank you this is ridiculously helpful - however in this case, I'm just looking at one state at a time e.g. pers_info['State'][1] since I have a larger loop in the background for a mail merge. When I add the [1] element I get an error that reads
  ''str' object has no attribute 'to_list'
Is there a way to fix that ? 

Again thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Ozymandias It is so much easier if you pass a `str`: `rf'(?<![^\W_]){Pers_info["State"][1]}(?![^\W_])'`, or `rf'(?<![^\W_]){re.escape(Pers_info["State"][1])}(?![^\W_])'`

Comment: Thanks, I am getting an empty array []. but I think I can figure it out - thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your Pers_info looks something like this:

```
Pers_info = {"state": ["Texas", "Alabama", "Florida"], "somethingelse": "stuff"}
```

And your files like this:

```
files = ["WORKFORCE_2017_ALABAMA_FILE.xlsx","WORKFORCE_2017_TEXAS_FILE.xlsx","SOMETHING.xlsx"]
```

(You don't need regex for this)

```
files = [file.lower() for file in files]
peers = [file.lower() for file in Pers_info['state']]
result = []

for x in peers:
    try:
        indx = peers.index(x)

        if any(peers[indx] in s for s in files):
            result.append(files[indx])
    except:
        break
print(result)
```